# Debugger takes too long(?) to show variables while debugging Tensorflow source code

Tags: tensorflow, gdb, bazel

I am trying to debug `Toco` tool from `TensorFlow` codebase. I am using the following setup:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- CLion 2019.1.4
- Bazel plugin v2019.07.08.0.2

Specifically, I am building the following bazel target:

```
tf_cc_binary(
    name = "toco",
    srcs = ["toco.cc"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        ":model",
        ":model_cmdline_flags",
        ":model_flags_proto_cc",
        ":toco_cmdline_flags",
        ":toco_convert",
        ":toco_flags_proto_cc",
        ":toco_port",
        ":toco_tooling",
        ":types_proto_cc",
        "@com_google_absl//absl/strings",
        "//tensorflow/core:lib",
        # We cannot embed the core:ops dependency directly into :toco_tooling as
        # it can conflict with downstream deps when toco is used as a library.
        "//tensorflow/core:ops",
    ],
)
```

with this command:
`bazel run -c dbg --strip=never //tensorflow/lite/toco:toco`

The debugger appears to be `gdb`.
My problem is that even if nothing changes in the code and I put a breakpoint to the very first line of `toco.cc` file, the debugger takes almost a minute to show the list of variables in the scope.

Let me explain what I mean. I see this output for the build process:

```
Analyzing: target //tensorflow/lite/toco:toco (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
INFO: Analyzed target //tensorflow/lite/toco:toco (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
[0 / 1] [Prepa] BazelWorkspaceStatusAction stable-status.txt
Target //tensorflow/lite/toco:toco up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/lite/toco/toco
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.246s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Build Event Protocol files produced successfully.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
```

This also happens fast:

```
Analyzing: target //tensorflow/lite/toco:toco (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
INFO: Analyzed target //tensorflow/lite/toco:toco (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
[0 / 1] [Prepa] BazelWorkspaceStatusAction stable-status.txt
Target //tensorflow/lite/toco:toco up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/lite/toco/toco
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.246s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Build Event Protocol files produced successfully.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
```

What takes longer is to arrive at the very first breakpoint in the very first line of the `main` function and show variables here:

[image]

But maybe I am wrong, maybe almost a minute for such a large project is ok? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is gonna hit this problem as well, try switching from the CLion bundled GDB to the one installed system-wide. Now it takes just a second to arrive at any breakpoint.

In my case, I switched from the bundled GDB v 8.2 to the system-wide of version 7.11.